# Long running Django Celery task close DB connection

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-celery, connection-timeout

I have a Django Celery task that performs long-running operations and sometimes loses connection to the database (Postgres).

the task looks like something like this:

```
@app.task(name='my_name_of_the_task')
def my_long_running_task(params):
   with transaction.atomic():
       object_list = self.get_object_list_from_params(params)
       for batch in batches(object_list):
           self.some_calculations()
           MyObject.objects.bulk_create(objs=batch) # <- here connection could be lost
```

I want to ensure the connection (but also be able to unit test this code).

For example:

```
@app.task(name='my_name_of_the_task')
def my_long_running_task(params):
   with transaction.atomic():
       object_list = self.get_object_list_from_params(params)
       for batch in batches(object_list):
           connection.connect()
           self.some_calculations()
           MyObject.objects.bulk_create(objs=batch) # <- here connection could be lost
```

This would work (because it always opens new connections) but the unit test throws the error that can't roll back on teardown.

I am thinking about

```
   @app.task(name='my_name_of_the_task')
    def my_long_running_task(params):
       with transaction.atomic():
           object_list = self.get_object_list_from_params(params)
           for batch in batches(object_list):
               try:
                   self.some_calculations()
                   MyObject.objects.bulk_create(objs=batch) # <- here connection could be lost
               except Exception e:
                   connection.connect()
                   MyObject.objects.bulk_create(objs=batch) # retry this insert
```

but is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Well that is the idea of a transaction: you use the same connection and after the transaction, it either commits all, or it is lost..

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem - what did you mean by this? That it is ok to do the last example?

Comment: One additional question that I think of now - would be atomicnes respected with this solution?